# If $\Delta u =1$ with $u=0$ on boundary, then $u(2/3,0) \le 13/18$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

> Let $u$ be such that $\Delta u =1$ in S=$\{x | |x| <1\}$ with $u=0$ on $\partial S$, then prove that $u(2/3,0) \le 13/18$.

Put $v=u-\frac{|x|^2}{4}$, then $v$ satisfies $\Delta v=0$ in S with $v=-\frac{|x|^2}{4}$ on $\partial S$ i.e. $v= -1/4$ on $\partial S$. Now we know a harmonic function attains its maximum at the boundary, therefore $v \le -1/4 \implies u \le |x|^2/4-1/4 \le 0$ on S, thus the the desired result is always true irrespective of the point. Is it correct?

Comment: I guess you mean the vector norm of $x$ in the definition of $v$?

Comment: yes, I meant $|x|^2$. Is the proof correct?

Comment: It is correct. In the first line you have typed $S$ in place of $\partial S$.

Comment: With that correction your proof is valid but it makes me wonder if something in the problem was copied wrong since your result is a lot stronger than the given one (and since you actually just solved the BVP completely, $u=(\| x \|^2-1)/4$).